# php complaining that abstract methods aren't implemented when they are, apache restart fixes it for a while

Tags: php

This problem started a few days ago.

The error message:

Fatal error: Class Session contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::open) in D:\xampp\htdocs\itasecure_class_session.php on line 38

Restarting apache fixes it, for a few hours or maybe a day or two, but then the error comes back.

For reference, the open() method most definitely is implemented.

Here's a snippet showing how the class and this particular method override are defined:

```
class Session implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    ...
    public function open ( $savePath, $sessionName )
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

PHP 7.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2017 02:06:32) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

P.S. This is *not* a question about how to implement abstract methods. This is a question about whether there's some obscure bug or configuration problem in php causing code that usually works to suddenly start having problems.